# WCF Client - How to handle SOAP server 1.1 sending response using SOAP 1.2 content type

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

My program need to query from a 3rd party web service which is in SOAP 1.1, I used VS 2013's Service References to create the web service for it from WSDL.

As it is a SOAP 1.1 Webservice, so I used basicHttpBinding in app.config, however when I run the program, it throw the error:

```
The content type application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><memberEnquiryResponse><errMsg>144859327293915198337416aFD&amp;EQshadfq2w</errMsg><result>0</result><member><name>test2</name><phone>85297350833</phone><securityCode>9702</securityCode><memberID>151983374</memberID></member><points>10000</points><pointExpiry>201701312359</pointExpiry><accTransactionAmount>0.00</accTransactionAmount><lastTransactionDatetime>-</lastTransactionDatetime><coupons><coupon><id>159</id><type>2</type><netOff>20</netOff><offType>0</offType><itemCode>DIS:</itemCode><name>Sandwiches (receipt discount $)</name><expiry>20161113</expiry><description>Coupon Description (Chi)</description></coupon><coupon><id>158</id><type>1</type><netOff>10</netOff><offType>1</offType><name>Soup (item discount %)</name><expiry>20161113</expiry><description>Coupon Description (Chi)</description></coupon><coupon><id>160</id><type>2</ty'.
```

I've found that the server side response's content-type is 
SOAP 1.2 application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8 instead of 
SOAP 1.1 text/xml; charset=utf-8

However, the name space it return is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
```

So I am quite sure it's a SOAP 1.1 web service.
As I cannot change the content-type from the server side (it's not control by me), the only way I can do is to either change the content-type once I receive the response, or to set the client to accept application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8 as SOAP 1.1 content type.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Have you tried using `wsHttpBinding` instead?  That supports SOAP 1.2.

Comment: @Tim Tried wsHttpBinding but it thrown me error that http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ is SOAP 1.1 and wsHttpBinding is SOAP1.2 and does not match